# finding the basis of an eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> > "Given the matrix $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}6 & 6\\-2 & -1\end{array}\right].$
> >
> > "The roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ are: $$\begin{align}\det(A-tI)=0 &\Leftrightarrow \det\left[\begin{array}{cc}6-t & 6\\-2 & -1-t\end{array}\right]=0\\ &\Leftrightarrow 6-5t+t^2=0\\ &\Leftrightarrow (t-2)(t-3)=0\\ &\Leftrightarrow t=2,3\end{align}$$ "So, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\fbox{2,3}.$ "

Then I subtract the diagonals by the eigenvalue $2$ and I guess  we are then supposed to find the rref but I get a different answer than the solution manual of my textbook:

> > "Now by using the reduced row echelon form, we have $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}2 & 3\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\end{array}\right]\Rightarrow 2x_1+3x_2=0.$$ "Therefore $x_1=3$ $x_2=-2$ satisfying the above equations.
> >
> > "Therefore, $\left[\begin{array}{c}3\\-2\end{array}\right]$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=2.$
> >
> > "So $\fbox{$\left\{\left[\begin{array}{c}3\\-2\end{array}\right]\right\}$}$ is a basis for the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda=2.$"

Shouldnt the RREF be

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 3/2\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]$$

so then the basis vector would be

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}-3/2\\1\end{array}\right]?$$

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have edited your post (and fixed the matrix at the beginning). Please let me know if any of my changes are not in the spirit of your original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is not wrong. (I do note, though, that your matrix $A$ at the beginning doesn't seem to match the rest of your post.) In fact, your sole basis vector is a non-zero multiple of their sole basis vector, so they span the same space (as they should). Note that the book simply asked for ***a*** basis. There are infinitely-many such, and yours is one of them.

Comment: so if im asked to find the matrix P to see diagonalizable I can use that number as well

Comment: You certainly can. It's usually "nicer" to use integer entries when possible for that purpose, which is probably why the book proceeded as it did.